# Links in email turn blue when email is forwarded

Tags: html, html-email

Creating a HTML email and the links of the email turn blue when it is forwarded in Outlook and Gmail (only tested those).

The links should be color: #3c4047 and work when email is sent normally but change to blue when forwarded and only when forwarded.

```
<h3 style="font-size: 18px; line-height: 24px; margin: 0 0 10px;">
    <a href="my-link" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; color: #3c4047;"><font face="'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif">Some text</font>
</a></h3>
```

Have also tried putting the color on all of the elements. Any thoughts on what the cause is?

Gmail adds this class:

```
.ii a[href] {
  color: #15c;
}
```

But I think this is standard, whats happening is the color styles are being stripped out when the email is forwarded in Outlook. Is this standard behavior when forwarding from Outlook?

Comment: Can you be a little clearer? Do you want to turn it blue or whaT?

Comment: Maybe these sites recognize it as a link and override your existing style.

Comment: As in the code, the color should be #3c4047.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add:

```
<style>
a:visited { color }
a:hover { color }
a:active { color }
</style>
```

to your e-mail.

Comment: All stylew we are adding inline, how this problem can be solved ??